# Можно ли запустить Genymotion и Android Studio на разных машинах?

Tags: android, genymotion

В целях быстродействия, хотелось бы запустить эмулятор и студию на разных машинах, возможно ли это ?

Comment: думаю, что можно. Надо только как-то прокинуть порт 5555(или любой другой, предварительно настроив его в Genymotion) на машине, где будет работать Genymotion. При помощи команды `adb connect <IP>:<PORT>` можно подключиться к удаленному устройству (или эмулятору).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да возможно. Genymotion все равно работает в виртуальной машине Oracle VM так что ему без разницы, а отладчику надо указать куда коннектиться.

Со стороны студии придется врукопашную запускать ADB с указанием IP адреса где запущен GenyMotion:

```
adb tcpip 5555 //говорим adb чтобы перешел в режим TCP/IP на порту 5555
adb connect 192.168.X.Y //коннектимся к хосту где запущен эмулятор
```

По идее должно сработать.

Comment: спасибо, попробуем

Comment: помог вот это совет https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/ov5ANqGf3DI

Comment: Ну был немного неправ, что Geny все равно, он поскольку сидит за 2-мя машинами (реальной и виртуальной) - нужен был мостик, который как раз и описан по вашей ссылке.